# How to Update beginAtZero in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have a graph that is already drawn. I'd like to toggle the beginAtZero property on the yAxis ticks: {beginAtZero: true} and use update() to force the graph to redraw so I don't have to reload the whole page.

Is this possible, and if so, how would one go about doing it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myBarChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.beginAtZero = false;   

// You probably also want to move your min :
myBarChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = 100;

// and call update:
// myBarChart.update();
```

Here's pen with some buttons if you want to experiment:

[Chart.js add/remove adjust data](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/gwdYzr?editors=0010)

Another thing you can do, is destroy and rebuild the chart :

[Chart.js Toggle Chart](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/zBXqYR)